# Inking in Windows Silverlight 8.1 app

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone, mouseevent, windows-phone-8-emulator

I was trying to implement [this program](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj662946%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) on my desktop(which has a touchscreen monitor) running a Windows Phone emulator(Emulator 8.1 WVGA 4 inch 512 MB) in Visual Studio 2013.

Now I changed the MyIP_MouseLeftButtonDown and MyIP_MouseMove functions to output some debugging data as shown below:

```
        private void MyIP_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            MyIP.CaptureMouse();
            StylusPointCollection MyStylusPointCollection = new StylusPointCollection();   

            MyStylusPointCollection.Add(e.StylusDevice.GetStylusPoints(MyIP));// MyIP is required here because it is the object with reference to which we get our stylus point's coordinates
            NewStroke = new Stroke(MyStylusPointCollection);
            Debug.WriteLine("Mouse Down"+MyStylusPointCollection.Count);

            MyIP.Strokes.Add(NewStroke);
        }


        private void MyIP_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            StylusPointCollection MyStylusPointCollection = new StylusPointCollection();
            MyStylusPointCollection.Add(e.StylusDevice.GetStylusPoints(MyIP));
            Debug.WriteLine("Mouse Move" + MyStylusPointCollection.Count);

            if (NewStroke != null)
                NewStroke.StylusPoints.Add(MyStylusPointCollection);
        }
```

Now there are 2 scenarios when running the app:

1. When I used my mouse to write on the canvas, in the first stroke only a dot was captured and the motion was not captured. When the mouse button was released and then again pressed to initiate a second stroke, the entire stroke was caprtured. The output and the canvas(attached picture) are:

   Mouse Down1
   Mouse Move1
   Mouse Down1
   Mouse Move1
   Mouse Move1
   Mouse Move1
   Mouse Move1
   Mouse Move1
   Mouse Move1
   Mouse Move1
   Mouse Move1
   [image]
2. When I used my finger to write on the canvas, the entire first stroke was captured and then the second stroke was also captured. The output and canvas(attached picture) are:

   Mouse Down1
   Mouse Move1
   Mouse Move1
   Mouse Move1
   Mouse Move1
   Mouse Move1
   Mouse Move1
   Mouse Move1
   Mouse Move1
   Mouse Move1
   Mouse Move1
   Mouse Down1  <--------2nd stroke started
   Mouse Move1
   Mouse Move1
   Mouse Move1
   Mouse Move1
   Mouse Move1
   Mouse Move1
   Mouse Move1
   Mouse Move1
   Mouse Move1
   Mouse Move1
   Mouse Move1
   Mouse Move1
   [image]

Can anybody tell me why the mouse doesn't work properly?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience with Ink it seems that sometimes the Move event does not arrive quick enough. This means that the mouse focus gets lost without some accumulated moves to have been reported. For example:

Mouse Down1
Mouse Move1
...[Mouse Move]s not reported but points get accumulated...
[Mouse Lost] is not handled with the coordinates from the last reported Mouse Move to the Lost point.

Can you try adding LostMouseCapture event listener, where you add the last point/segment where the mouse was lost?